# Wicket: templatized javascript in <body>?

Tags: java, javascript, templates, wicket

Previously I've used [TextTemplateHeaderContributor.forJavaScript()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/template/TextTemplateHeaderContributor.html#forJavaScript%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.wicket.model.IModel%29) to add Javascript to the page `<head>` from a template file.

Is there any way to do the same thing, but have the interpolated JS appear in the page `<body>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See org.apache.wicket.util.template.TextTemplate and its family.
You can feed it, interpolate and get its content (#getString()), then you can render the string in a Label for example.